# Is it possible to change/remove Pages' table row/column size limits?

Tags: pages, iwork, formatting, macos

I want to make a row in a table super thin but Pages has a 0.28in minimum for rows when auto-resize is turned on and a 0.11in minimum for rows when auto-resize is turned off.

I searched everywhere but all I could find were posts explaining how to resize a table and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245739/numbers-how-can-i-make-rows-and-columns-smaller-than-9-points) post. Since that post is about Numbers (and has no solution), I thought I might ask this question to see if someone has a solution for Pages.

Has anyone been able to overcome this restriction?